How to make ICU stop early when meeting 65533?
I want to use icu to validate whether a stream of bytes is encoded in GB2312:
bool is_gb2312(char *data, size_t len) {
    UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;

    UConverter* conv = ucnv_open("GB2312", &status);
    if (U_FAILURE(status)) {
        std::cerr << "ucnv_open failed" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    auto* output = new UChar[len * 2];
    UChar* target = output;

    char const* source = data;
    ucnv_toUnicode(conv, &target, output + len * 2, &source, data + len, nullptr, true, &status);

    if (U_FAILURE(status)) {
        std::cerr << "ucnv_toUnicode failed" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    delete[] output;
    ucnv_close(conv);
    return true;
}

I found that it never reports an error even if there are invalid bytes (e.g., 0xA1 0xA0), and it just converts it into 65533 (replacement character). How to make it stop early and report error as soon as it meets 65533?

What language is that?  std::cerr looks like C++, but unqualified size_t looks like C.

@TobySpeight I think new and delete imply C++. Also many compilers (including gcc and clang) support unqualified size_t - see here (MSVC also supports it, but it's broken in Godbolt at the moment).

side note : auto* output = new UChar[len * 2]; in C++ use std::vector<UChar> output(2*len); (using naked new/deletes is not recommended)

@TobySpeight see Difference between size_t and std::size_t, The header <cstddef> may or may not declare ::size_t

Exactly @phuclv - including <cstddef> will declare std::size_t, but can't be assumed to provide ::size_t.

Anyway, the question has now been tagged with a language, even if the code is incomplete.

It can be achieved by adding a callback, so that the error can be caught on-the-fly:
    ucnv_setToUCallBack(conv, UCNV_TO_U_CALLBACK_STOP, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, &status);
    if (U_FAILURE(status)) {
        std::cerr << "ucnv_setToUCallBack failed" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

